# systemd service not starting on boot

Tags: debian, systemd

Whenever I reboot my Debian Jessie box NZBget fails to start. It has already been enabled with `sudo systemctl enable nzbget`

If I do:

```
$ sudo systemctl status nzbget
* nzbget.service - NZBGet
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nzbget.service; enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2016-02-20 12:14:55 GMT; 1min 15s ago
Process: 381 ExecStop=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -Q (code=exited,status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 263 ExecStart=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -D (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

If I do a `sudo system start nzbget` then it starts.

here is the service file in `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/nzbget.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=NZBGet
After=network.target
RequiresMountsFor=/<pathtomount>

[Service]
User=osmc
Group=osmc
ExecStart=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -D
ExecStop=/opt/nzbget/nzbget -Q

# process will demonize and parent return ok
Type=forking
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
# Needed to run nzbget at boot
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any suggestions as to the issue

```
 -- Logs begin at Sat 2016-02-20 12:31:40 GMT, end at Sun 2016-02-21 10:53:14 GMT. --
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: nzbget.conf(70): Invalid value for option "TempDir" (/home/osmc/Downloads/tmp/): could not read information for dir
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: nzbget.conf(67): Invalid value for option "QueueDir" (/home/osmc/Downloads/queue/): could not read information for 
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[279]: nzbget.conf(61): Invalid value for option "NzbDir" (/home/osmc/Downloads/nzb/): could not read information for dire
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: /home/osmc/Downloads/nzbget.log: No such file or directory
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: nzbget.conf(70): Invalid value for option "TempDir" (/home/osmc/Downloads/tmp/): could not read information for dir
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: nzbget.conf(67): Invalid value for option "QueueDir" (/home/osmc/Downloads/queue/): could not read information for 
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: nzbget.conf(61): Invalid value for option "NzbDir" (/home/osmc/Downloads/nzb/): could not read information for dire
Feb 20 12:31:43 osmc nzbget[391]: Unable to send request to nzbget-server at 127.0.0.1 (port 6789)
```

Comment: Check the output of `sudo journalctl -u nzbget` to see why it crashed.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas as to why it fails to start?

Comment: Looks like `/home/osmc/Downloads` doesn't exist or isn't readable? Is it maybe mounted only later in the boot process?

Comment: Spot on. Edited accordingly ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See edit above. Needed this in the [unit] section:
`RequiresMountsFor=/<pathtomount>`

Now all is working as the service begins after the external drive is mounted